# how to kill/stop a jquery/javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function :

```
function getArrowScroll(dirX, dirY, ele)
            {
                return function()
                {
                    arrowScroll(dirX, dirY, this, ele);
                    this.blur();
                    return false;
                };
            }
```

When the user hover the arrowDown button, it will auto scrolling the contents inside a div :

```
if (settings.arrowScrollOnHover) {
    arrowUp.bind('mouseover.jsp', getArrowScroll(0, -1, arrowUp));

    arrowDown.bind('mouseover.jsp', getArrowScroll(0, 1, arrowDown));
}
```

When the scroll bar reach the bottom of div, jquery get more data from other page and add them to the div. At this point, `mouseover.jsp` is lost control already because I reinitialize everything except getArrowScroll(). It will keep scrolling down continuously non-stop by executing `getArrowScroll(0, 1, arrowDown)`. I need kill function getArrowScroll(0, 1, arrowDown) before reinitialize, or when
`mouseleave.jsp`. If I put :

```
arrowDown.bind('mouseover.jsp',
getArrowScroll(0, 1, arrowDown)).bind('mouseleave.jsp',
getArrowScroll(0, 0, arrowDown));
```

it will still scrolling to bottom
because getArrowScroll(0, 1, arrowDown) is still running, how to kill or stop
function getArrowScroll()?

Comment: give a condition in your getArrowScroll function for pageX

Comment: Have you tried the stop method? http://bit.ly/5h0HKd

Comment: @ gutierrezalex, I have tried it. It won't stop the scrolling because getArrowScroll(0, 1, arrowDown) is still running.